# Why does C# sometimes print the contents of an array without any sort of iteration?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm writing a simple hangman program. In that program, I have an array being made from an existing string like this:

```
char[] hiddenWord = hiddenWordString.ToCharArray();
```

To print array contents, you have to iterate through them somehow, using foreach or some sort of for loop. However, for some reason, I can print this array's contents simply with:

```
Console.WriteLine(hiddenWord);
```

Why is this so? I tried doing the same thing with another array and I got the standard message that says the type of array it is, not the contents of the array.

Comment: char[] is very likely to contain something worth looking at.  So it gets special treatment, both by the debugger and Console.WriteLine.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [overload of Console.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Char___) 
 for `char[]` arguments which writes the contents of the array as unicode.